# Casting request objects in zope to an array

Tags: python, types, zope

Using zope and request objects, sometimes I get different types in my variable. I need to account for this:

```
docs = request.form['ID']
```

Sometimes docs is a single id (and is a string), other items it's several ids, and is an array. This can be very confusing because strings are iterable also.

```
if isinstance(docs, basestring):
    docs = [docs]

for doc_id in docs:
    dosomething(doc_id)
```

This works, but only if the variables coming in are strings.

What's the best way to deal with request types that change? Perhaps in my case I want to only want to cast the types that are iterable (and wrong), and throw errors on the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Zope supports type conversion out-of-the-box, including list conversion:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="items:list" value="foo" /> Foo<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="items:list" value="bar" /> Bar<br/>
```

If a user were to check one or two of the above items, the resulting `items` entry in the request will be a list, regardless of the number of items in the list:

```py
# No typechecking needed, this is a list:
items = request.form['items']
```

In the above example, I used the postfix `:list` to accomplish this. See the [Argument Conversion section of the Object Publishing chapter of the Zope dev book](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/ObjectPublishing.html#argument-conversion) for further details.